# Merge PDF's to a common PDF without whitespace PDF-Framework Java/C#

Tags: c#, java, pdf

I am looking for a PDF-Framework in Java which can merge several PDF's to one common PDF. Additionally I don't want have spaces between the several PDF's in the common PDF. The common PDF must to be a fluent file. Any tip is welcome!!!

```
File1.pdf       File2.pdf
a               a
b               b
c               c
d               d   
                e
                f
                g

Common.pdf
a
b
c
d   //ignore the 3 whitespace lines
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Comment: In c# I have used wnvpdfmerge.dll [link]( http://www.winnovative-software.com/PDF-Merge.aspx) to merge pdf files. They have got sample code as well.

Comment: @Mokchhya thanks for your tip; I look at your Tip, when I have time

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a tool, which merges halfway through the page? I don't think such a tool exists, cause you would lose stuff like headers and footers in the subsequent pages and images that would be lost in the page overlap as well.

If you're OK with using a tool that merges at the end of each PDF (so with page breaks) you should look at building your own library around [QPdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/), which is an open-source tool and best in class imho.